# Calling a Webservice based on Routing from browser URL

Tags: .net, web-services, routes

I have created a Basic Webservice which gets invoked as per the Routing defined in the DTO.Here is my sample Routing Code..

```
[Route("/students", Verbs = "GET")] 
[Route("/students/{id}", Verbs = "GET")]
public class StudentRequestDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Now when i am calling this webservice directly by `http://localhost:1661/Students` URL i am able to get the response whereas when i am trying to call it by `http://localhost:1661/Students?id=1`then i am getting `NullReferenceException` .

Is my way of calling the Service second time by `http://localhost:1661/Students?id=1` URL correct , if not what is the correct way..Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[Route("/students/{id}", Verbs = "GET")]
```

only matches:

```
http://localhost:1661/students/1
```